# Cannot get data from TCP port xxx.xx.xxx.xx:6556: (111, 'Connection refused')

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, nagios

I am using nagios with OMD. I have added Windows 2008 R2 hosts using WATO on nagios UI. The check_mk_agent is installed on Windows 2008 R2 hosts. While inventorying the services from that host I am getting following error.

```
Cannot get data from TCP port xxx.xx.xxx.xx:6556: (111, 'Connection refused')
```

How can I resolve this error?